# Efficient way to freeze a process and resume it

Tags: java, time, freeze, timing

The problem is quite simple, I have a program that runs for a period of time,
let's say that at some point the condition to freeze the program and wait becames true,
once the program is freezed it doesn't do anything, but after 2 hour of sleep it have to be resumed and run again.

I looking for efficient way(in Java) to put to sleep a program, resume it, and check cyclically if it have to be freezed or resumed.

Comment: Would there be a case when you want to "wake it up" before 2 hours have passed?

Comment: You may want to start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) or (even better) from the beginning of the tutorial.

Comment: No, it have to wait till the time has passed, in other words i need to set the "alarm clock".

Comment: Then look directly at the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) I already provided. About `Thread.sleep()` method.